# How to observe for changes in web service and update ui using RxAndroid?

Tags: android, android-volley, rx-java, rx-android

What I want to achieve is to be able to observe changes in my web service and then update my textview if there is any change. I am currently using timer to achieve this by running it every x second. The problem though, is that the memory leaks so it's not a good solution. Now I stumbled upon this rxjava/rxjava but I'm confused on how to use it. The documentation is confusing to me and I can't find alot of tutorials about this. I am using volley to get data from my web service by the way.

this is the Observable that someone on answered on my other question but I'm getting an error which is "Incompatible types" on return sendRequest.

```
Observable.interval(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, Schedulers.io()).map(new Func1<Long, Object>() {
        @Override
        public Object call(Long tick) {
            return sendRequest();
        }
    }).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe();
```

here is my volley request code

```
public void sendRequest(){

    //While the app fetched data we are displaying a progress dialog
    //final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Fetching Data","Please wait...",false,false);

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(JSON_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    //text.setText(response);

                    //loading.dismiss();
                    showJSON(response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void showJSON(String json){
    ParseJson pj = new ParseJson(json);
    pj.parseJSON();
    text.setText(ParseJson.playing[0]);
}
```

Comment: You don't need rxJava for sending continuous requests to a server. Use an Android Handler or Timer to resend the volley request. Don't confuse yourself with rxJava if you don't need to

Answer (score 0):

Your method `sendRequest` doesn't return anything(`void`). You can either return `null` or something.

```
@Override
public Object call(Long tick) {
  sendRequest();
  return null;
}
```

I would suggest you firstly read `Java basics` instead of writing Android app.

Comment: It doesn't need to return anything. It's an asynchronous call. Also, how would Java basics teach anything about volley or rxJava?

Comment: @cricket_007 so why he gets `Incompatible types` error on return `sendRequest`?

Comment: Is that a compile error? Because Java shouldn't let you return a void method anyways.

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks for clarification. If he fix this error everything will work as he wants. And this is basics of `java`, it has no relation to `rxjava` or `volley`.

Comment: Seeing as that method is part of the rxjava map function it is more than basic java. You could make the map go from Long to Void, then a return wouldn't be necessary. And in that case, map is the wrong method

Answer (score 0):

Use push notifications to send messages from the server to the users when data is updated and avoid sending unwanted requests to the server.

Then you can send the request for new data only when notified and update the Observer someway, maybe use a rx subject, or better store the data in SQLite table and observe changes from the DB.

Recommend this to create a rx stream from sqlite
https://github.com/square/sqlbrite

GCM: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/

Comment: That's assuming OP has control over the server to setup GCM

Comment: Of course, but pulling the server like he is doing is a bad idea. I'm thinking on a production app if this is just a prototype... never mind